# Adding fragment to a specific view

Tags: android

I am trying to show a map in a Dialog (using LovelyDialog)

what i want is to add the map to the FrameLayout but i get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d00ab for fragment SupportMapFragment{c2cd779 #1 id=0x7f0d00ab}
```

However,this works when i use `DialogFragment`

this is my code :

```
   Dialog show = new LovelyCustomDialog(this)
                            .setTopColorRes(R.color.yellow)
                            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera)
                            .setView(R.layout.fragment_maps)
                            .configureView(new LovelyCustomDialog.ViewConfigurator() {

                                @Override
                                public void configureView(final View v) {


                                    FrameLayout mapContainer= (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);

                                    SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
                                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                    transaction.add(mapContainer.getId(), fragment).commit();



                                }
                            })
                            .show();
```

and this is my layout file :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutMain"
    android:padding="0dp" >


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If it works for `DialogFragment` then your `LovelyCustomDialog` could extend it

Comment: LovelyCustomDialog already extends a class ,this is a repo from Github.@JuanCruzSoler